# WSO2 ESB and MB Message Store looses Message Body

Tags: wso2, message, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

i m trying to face up to the integration between WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and WSO2 MB 2.1.0, following the instructions written at this URL:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/MB210/Integrating+WSO2+ESB

In particular i want to use a message store as a queue. So i follow the paragraph: "Integrate Using Message Stores and Processors".

I created the message store and message processor, having previously well configured ESB and MB as showed.
Finally i wrote this proxy:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MessageStoreQueueProxy"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://localhost:8080/RestService/rest/servizio"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
    <send/>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
    <store messageStore="JMSMS"/>
    <log level="full"/>                    
  </outSequence>
</target>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

When my client calls the MessageStoreQueueProxy service, on the Message Broker i can see the "JMSMS message store" counter rightly increased but, when i take a look on the "Content Type" field of each message i see just the "Java MessageObject icon", while, in the "body field", i can read just a "not supported" value.

On the other hand, if i browse the JMSMS "message store" in the ESB i can see that the messages' envelopes look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <root>
        <code>ok</code>
        <documentID>2546</documentID>
     </root>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So why the body was lost during the transaction? how can i mantain the body? or how can i recover it from the ObjectMessage in the WSO2 MB?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

"Message Store" does not persist the message as it is in the JMS Queue. it serializes the message and other information into java serialized object and put it into JMS Queue.When "Message Processor" processes the message, it pulls Messages from JMS Queue and deserializes the java serialized object to further process.

Here MB is used as JMS Queue. So Message Store serialize and put in MB queue. So you see serialize java object. If you use message store you won't be able see the content in MB.